# Align content in two columns in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been banging my head against the wall for hours now and have looked everywhere for a solution... so now I need to post to see if someone can help. I have an image in 1 column and text 1 column.

I would like the image to align right and the text to align left.

However, when I do this, there is a lot of space between each column.

I tried to remove padding but it did not work. Also, when the viewport is in mobile size, the image needs to be centered after the breakpoint.

When I use `<div class="col-md-6 text-right">`, the image appears on the right when on mobile. Any ideas? thank you!!!

```
 <!-- jumbotron  start-->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right"> <img src="images/cover-lg.jpg" alt="Cover"> 
          </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 title-xs-hide">
          <p class="title" ><i>MyTitle</p>
          <h1>Year In Review 2017</h1>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background-color:#ed8e20; border-radius:5px; border-color: #ed8e20;"  href="#" role="button">Sign In To Access Your Copy</a></p>
          <br>

          <p class="account">Don't have an account? <br>
            <a href="#">Create a free account for immediate access.</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- jumbotron  end-->
```

Comment: There should be a </i> tag after "MyTitle"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `text-right` you can use `text-lg-right`.

Also, you can remove the gutter space using `pr-0` and `pl-0` classes to the respective sections.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/goxXvq)

Answer (score 0):

You could add classes `text-md-right text-center` to the column with the image so it's centered on mobile and right aligned after certain breakpoint.

If you want to remove space you can just set `padding: 0` on both columns.

Here's the example:
https://codepen.io/apieceofbart/pen/RxZLzx

Comment: Bless you both! 'text-md-right text-center' worked. Now, where did you find that class and HOW to use it in Bootstrap? I feel like I am missing a lot of parts the documentation.

thank You!!!

Comment: @user1913879 I find bootstrap documentation pretty straightforward. You can read the docs at http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/. Search for your requirement in the top-left search field. So simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Set paddings for col-md-6 to

like

```
 <style>
.col-md-6{
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}

</style>
```